# Fitnesse Maven Classpath error

Tags: java, fitnesse, acceptance-testing, fitnesse-slim

I am trying to set up Fitnesse on my current project.

pom.xml configuration has:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fitnesse/fitnesse -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.fitnesse</groupId>
    <artifactId>fitnesse</artifactId>
    <version>20161106</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.fitnesse.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-classpath-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>start-fitnesse</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                        <echo taskname="fitnesse" message="Starting FitNesse..." />
                        <java classname="fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain" classpathref="maven.runtime.classpath" fork="true">
                            <arg line="-p 8000" />
                            <arg line="-d ." />
                        </java>
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Without creating the plugins.properties, i am able to bring up the fitnesse server. But, I have to bring in the maven dependencies to run fitnesse tests for which I created a plugins.properties file next to pom.xml. The plugins.properties has:

```
SymbolTypes = fitnesse.wikitext.widgets.MavenClasspathSymbolType
```

Now when I add this file, I get the following error while starting the server:

```
main:
 [fitnesse] Starting FitNesse...
     [java] SEVERE: Error while starting the FitNesse [Unable to instantiate component for type fitnesse.wikitext.widgets.MavenClasspathSymbolType]
     [java] fitnesse.components.ComponentInstantiationException: Unable to instantiate component for type fitnesse.wikitext.widgets.MavenClasspathSymb
olType
     [java]     at fitnesse.components.ComponentFactory.createComponent(ComponentFactory.java:75)
     [java]     at fitnesse.plugins.PropertyBasedPluginFeatureFactory$8.register(PropertyBasedPluginFeatureFactory.java:152)
     [java]     at fitnesse.plugins.PropertyBasedPluginFeatureFactory.forEachClass(PropertyBasedPluginFeatureFactory.java:144)
     [java]     at fitnesse.plugins.PropertyBasedPluginFeatureFactory.forEachObject(PropertyBasedPluginFeatureFactory.java:150)
     [java]     at fitnesse.plugins.PropertyBasedPluginFeatureFactory.registerSymbolTypes(PropertyBasedPluginFeatureFactory.java:75)
     [java]     at fitnesse.plugins.PluginsLoader.loadSymbolTypes(PluginsLoader.java:87)
     [java]     at fitnesse.ContextConfigurator.makeFitNesseContext(ContextConfigurator.java:151)
     [java]     at fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain.launchFitNesse(FitNesseMain.java:69)
     [java]     at fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain.launchFitNesse(FitNesseMain.java:58)
     [java]     at fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain.main(FitNesseMain.java:38)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
     [java]     at fitnesse.components.ComponentFactory.createComponent(ComponentFactory.java:72)
     [java]     ... 9 more
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.makeComputingMap(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/util/c
oncurrent/ConcurrentMap;
     [java]     at com.google.inject.internal.Annotations$AnnotationChecker.<init>(Annotations.java:104)
     [java]     at com.google.inject.internal.Annotations.<clinit>(Annotations.java:122)
     [java]     at com.google.inject.Key.ensureRetainedAtRuntime(Key.java:362)
     [java]     at com.google.inject.Key.strategyFor(Key.java:354)
     [java]     at com.google.inject.Key.get(Key.java:222)
     [java]     at org.sonatype.guice.bean.binders.ParameterKeys.<clinit>(ParameterKeys.java:23)
     [java]     at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer$ContainerModule.configure(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:801)
     [java]     at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:229)
     [java]     at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
     [java]     at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:80)
     [java]     at org.sonatype.guice.bean.binders.MergedModule.configure(MergedModule.java:54)
     [java]     at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:229)
     [java]     at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
     [java]     at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:136)
     [java]     at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
     [java]     at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:94)
     [java]     at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:71)
     [java]     at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:61)
     [java]     at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:470)
     [java]     at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:196)
     [java]     at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:160)
     [java]     at fitnesse.wikitext.widgets.MavenClasspathExtractor.buildPlexusContainer(MavenClasspathExtractor.java:219)
     [java]     at fitnesse.wikitext.widgets.MavenClasspathExtractor.buildPlexusContainer(MavenClasspathExtractor.java:215)
     [java]     at fitnesse.wikitext.widgets.MavenClasspathExtractor.<init>(MavenClasspathExtractor.java:51)
     [java]     at fitnesse.wikitext.widgets.MavenClasspathSymbolType.<init>(MavenClasspathSymbolType.java:39)
     [java]     ... 14 more
     [java] Java Result: 1
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.552 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-27T12:58:00-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/500M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "fitnesse" could not be activated because it does not exist.
```

What do I have to do get Fitnesse working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have another library on your runtime classpath that uses a newer version of guice than used by the maven classpath plugin. I had something similar when I placed selenium on the classpath when running tests: that broke the maven classpath plugin.

I now use two strategies to run fitnesse tests:

1. When running the wiki locally I use the maven classpath plugin, but I start the wiki using the 'standalone.jar' (`java -jar fitness-standalone.zip -p 8000`) and I place the plugin's jar with dependencies (maven classifier 'jar-with-dependencies') in a 'plugins' subdirectory. That way none of my fixture's dependencies are on the wiki's classpath (the wiki starts a new JVM, with a classpath generated by the maven plugin, to run the fixtures, in which the maven classpath plugin is not used). So there are no conflicts with dependencies.
2. When I debug fixtures I start FitNesse and the tests in the same JVM, with a classpath generated by my IDE. In that case I don't need the maven classpath plugin (as the classpath has already be generated based on the pom.xml by the IDE). Then I ensure the maven classpath plugin is deactivated by setting the system property `fitnesse.wikitext.widgets.MavenClasspathSymbolType.Disable` to `true`. Then the wiki does understand the `!pom` symbol in the wiki, but the plugin itself is does not try to figure out all maven dependencies, preventing the exception you encountered.

Full details can be found in the [pom.xml](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/blob/master/pom.xml) of my [FitNesse fixtures/project baseline](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures). And a [sample using that baseline to take care of all this is available as a separate project](https://github.com/fhoeben/sample-fitnesse-project).

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I moved up the fitnesse dependencies to the top of the dependency list and that worked for me. But I will definitely use the above mentioned strategies.

Comment: I have ran into another issue while setting up Fitnesse. Could you please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556752/fitnesse-maven-classpath-plugin-conflicting-with-guava-jar

Comment: That seems like exactly the same issue: dependency conflicts between maven-classpath-plugin and your fixtures. Use of the strategies I mention here to prevent these. I believe its the same issue, but just guave instead of guice.

Comment: Thanks Fried...I wasn't getting the time to do that...But I guess now I have to go with your suggestions.